# compose a statistical equation of estimator of coin flip

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have the following situation. You will flip a coin (which might be biased) $n$ times independently. The probability for 'head' is $p$. Suppose you observe $k=10$ times head and $n-k = 2$ times tail (so $n = 12$). In the tutorial exercise, I need to do the following things

1. What do you estimate $p$ to be?
2. Can you give a statistical equation for your estimator?

Isn't the esimate not just simply $p = \frac{10}{12}$, or for the 'statistical equation' $n,k$ variable, $p = \frac{k}{n}$?

I have the feeling I'm not fully understanding the question. Could somehow give me a direction to look at?